# sed match pattern and substitute in html

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I want to substitute text in-between only specific html tag, example html file

```
<html>
<head>
original text
<title>original text</title>
original text
<head>
<body>
original text
</body>
</html>
```

Here I want to replace text "original" by "modified" only in-between the tag "title" I tried the following but that replaces everywhere except before title tag. I do need to keep global "g".

```
 sed -i '' '/<title>/,/<\/title>/ s/original/modified/g' test.html
```

Also, I don't understand why do I need ''(two single quote) in my script, for example this one works well (with double quotes)

```
 sed -i -e "s/original/modified/g" test.html
```

if I have match pattern then the below one doesn't work

```
 sed -i -e "/first/,/last/ s/original/modified/g" test.html
```

and I need to have '' to get it work as below

```
  sed -i '' '/first/,/last/ s/original/modified/' test.html
```

I am using Mac OSX 10.9, also not sure of a better way to do this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First '' is due to option -i

> `-i[SUFFIX]'`--in-place[=SUFFIX]'
>        This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU
>        `sed' does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to
>        this file rather than to the standard output.(1).

sed work line by line by default and pattern address (/start/,/end/) define the line to start until which OTHER line containing the end parttern so in your case where  is on the same line, sed start at  and stop at the end of file, not like expected

assuming the are always on the same line in your case

```
sed -i '' '/<title>/ {
: loop
   s|\(<title>.*\)original\(.*</title>\)|\1modified\2|
   t loop
   }' test.html
```

Comment: nice explanation, thanks. But still I don't get the use of ''(two single quotes)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `awk`

```
awk '/title/ {sub(/original/,"modified")}1' test.hmtl
<html>
<head>
orginal text
<title>modified text</title>
original text
<head>
<body>
original text
</body>
</html>
```

Change original file

```
awk '/title/ {sub(/original/,"modified")}1' test.hmtl > tmp && mv tmp test.hmtl
```